# How do I do these conditional bashes?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a .txt file, it contains many names, each in its own separate line.
With conditional bashes I have to echo a "Yes" or "No" to the following:

1. Is there a repeating name?
2. Is the first name in the .txt file the name which would also be the first if the .txt was alphabetically ordered?
3. Does the .txt file contain a specific name? (as specified in the bash)

I tried my best but I can't even finish the first one;

```
if [ sort names.txt | uniq -c > 1]; then echo "Yes"; else echo "No"; fi
```

I'm not even truly sure what this did either.

How can do any of this?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few issues with your attempt at Q1:

1. inside `[  ]` test brackets, `>` is the ordinary output redirection operator. (Inside a `[[  ]]` extended test, `>` is a comparison operator, but it compares arguments *lexicographically* rather than numerically.)
2. `[` and `[[` tests are [picky about whitespace](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117438/why-are-bash-tests-so-picky-about-whitespace)

Taken together, these mean that what your command does is create a file named `1]` in the current directory, then throw an error because it can't find a matching `]` for the `[`.

3. `sort names.txt | uniq -c` writes to standard output - if you want to test that against something, you need to capture standard output using a *command substitution*
4. `uniq -c` doesn't produce a simple count, instead it produces multiline output like

   ```
      1 bar
      2 foo
   ```

What you might consider instead is using `sort | uniq -d`, which will produce output only if there are duplicate lines, capturing its output, and testing whether the result is an empty string or not:

```
  -z STRING      True if string is empty.

  -n STRING
     STRING      True if string is not empty.
```

So for example:

```
if [ -n "$(sort Names.txt | uniq -d)" ]; then echo "duplicates"; else echo "no duplicates"; fi
```

or

```
if [ -z "$(sort Names.txt | uniq -d)" ]; then echo "unique"; else echo "non unique"; fi
```

---

Alternatively, you could replace `uniq` with `sort -Cu` to (quietly) check whether the sorted file is strictly ordered. In this case, you can test the pipeline's *exit status* rather than its standard output:

```
if sort Names.txt | sort -Cu; then echo "no duplicates"; else echo "duplicates"; fi
```

For Q2 and Q3 it will depend on the format of the file - but you might have success with `cut` and `grep` or with `awk`.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment! :D I need to learn more about these sorts of command structures than I thought.

Comment: Oops (1) is just plain wrong - deleting while I fix it

Comment: @JohnnyJohnson OK (1) should be correct now I think

Answer (score 0):

`[ sort file | uniq -d ]` will always read the whole file.

If the file is big, this might be very slow even if the possible duplicate is in the very beginning.

You could use `awk`, which will be **much** faster. It will stop after first duplicate found and there is no need to sort it first.

```bash
awk 'seen[$0]++ {print "duplicates"}' file
```

or more enhanced:

```bash
awk '
    seen[$0]++ {dupes=1; exit}
    END {if (dupes) print "duplicates"; else print "no duplicates"}
' file
```

---

If you need to use it as part of a `bash` condition, you can assign a return value:

```bash
awk 'BEGIN{ret=1} seen[$0]++ {ret=0; exit} END{exit ret}' file
```

e.g.

```bash
if awk 'BEGIN{ret=1} seen[$0]++ {ret=0; exit} END{exit ret}' file; then
    echo "duplicates"
else
    echo "no duplicates"
fi
```

---

Regarding your other questions:

Compare first words:

```bash
if [ "$(sort file | head -n1)" =  "$(head -n1 file)" ]; then echo "First line is same as sorted"; fi
```

Check if a specific word is in the file:

```bash
if grep -q "specific_word" file; then echo "Found"; fi
```